# How to calculate gain for a instrumentation amplifier given differential input voltage and the output voltage

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

> Calculate the value of gain resistance, Rg, if the differential input voltage is 0.3 V and the output voltage is 9 V. All other resistance values can be assumed as 10 kΩ.

I know the formula for gain of an instrumentation amplifier is:

$$\mathrm{Gain} = \left[1+\frac{R_\mathrm{F1} + R_\mathrm{F2}}{R_\mathrm G}\right]\left[\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right]$$

It is given in the question that we can assume all resistances to be 10 kΩ but what will be the value of the gain? Is it (output voltage - differential input voltage)?

How do I calculate the gain from the values given in the question?

No circuit is mentioned in the question, but it's most probably this:

[image]

Comment: Which configuration of InAmp are you referring to? There are a few so, it's best to show the circuit in your question rather than have folk take guesses.

Comment: Let's see how far you've got by yourself, we don't just do homework for you on this site. What's the gain of A3, with all 10k resistors? So then what's the gain of A1/A2? Write that as the gain for your formula, and do a 7th grade algebraic rearrange to get Rg. Oops, I;ve just noticed that the formula includes A3's gain. That means you can rearrange the formula right now with all 10k resistors. Are you asking us to do the formula rearrangement? Gain is a ratio, output voltage / input voltage, not a difference, output voltage - input voltage.

Comment: Thanks @Neil_UK the last part was all i needed to know. I knew that Gain must be unitless, i jdon't know why i didn't think about taking ratio. Thanks again.

Comment: Please ask the actual question in the title. This site is full of "Questions related to Instrumentation amplifier". Be specific.